# Mongodb ipv6 inside docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, ipv6

I'm running the standard mongodb container (with a modified docker entrypoint and config)
I've tried change the config file and start up script to work with with my IPv6 address or :: (all/any) I've tried including --ipv6 which different posts say is either needed or no longer used. It also seems that when the mongo config tried to bind to all ipv6 addresses I loose internet connectivity for the entire container (can't use apt update).

docker command:
`docker run -d -v /Docker/entrypoint/:/usr/local/bin/ -v /Docker/mongoconfig/mongod.conf.orig:/etc/mongod.conf.orig -p 27017:27017 mongo:5.0.3`

I've tried with different docker entrypoint code.

try 1 docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec mongod --bind_ip '::' --ipv6
```

try 2 docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec mongod --bind_ip [134:1234:134:1324:1234:134:1234:3]
```

try 3 docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec mongod --bind_ip [134:1234:134:1324:1234:134:1234:3] --ipv6
```

try 4 docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec mongod --bind_ip_all
```

the mongo config pretty much stayed the same swapping the bind IP and ipv6 by commenting out as seen here:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  #bindIp: 134:1234:134:1324:1234:134:1234:3
  bind_ip = 0::0
  ipv6 = true
```

ps -auxwe output
`root           1  0.8  5.4 1540940 111092 ?      Ssl  09:38   0:01 mongod --bind_ip :: --ipv6 HOSTNAME=6cb245ebc947 PWD=/ HOME=/root MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org`

netstat output

```
netstat -anp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:45684        91.189.88.152:80        TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:39324        91.189.91.38:80         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:54468        91.189.88.142:80        TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:40844        13.227.219.90:80        TIME_WAIT   -                   
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1635933  1/mongod             /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

mongoshell:

```
mongo --ipv6 [134:1234:134:1324:1234:134:1234:3]:27017/local
MongoDB shell version v5.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://[134%31234%3134%31324%31234%3134%31234%33]:27017/local?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server [134:1234:134:1324:1234:134:1234:3]:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to [134:1234:134:1324:1234:134:1234:3]:27017 (134:1234:134:1324:1234:134:1234:3:27017) :: caused by :: No route to host :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
```

when I passed only --ipv6 to the entrypoint my netstat did acknowledge mongo listening`mongod --ipv6`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/mongod            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:27017               :::*                    LISTEN      1/mongod
```

Comment: Just to add, I can see from the log from Mongo that it can't find the IPv6 address. no matter what I use.
```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-02T11:50:21.623+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23021,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Found no addresses for peer","attr":{"peer":{"code":7,"codeName":"HostNotFound","errmsg":"Could not find address for [[::]]:27017: SocketException: Host not found (authoritative)"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ideal answer - but its a good workaround until a better answer is provided.

By adding a second network I was able to get mongo server to serve other containers.
/
I followed answers from another question on Stack overflow:
after creating my two containers and ensuring they had IPv6 connectivity, I stopped them and ran the below commands.

```
$ docker network create network2
$ docker network connect network2 container_name1
$ docker network connect network2 container_name2
$ docker start container_name1
$ docker start container_name2
```

I then was able to tell container 1 to reach out to Container 2 via the Docker private IPv4 address.
it also seems that after screwing around with the config file I need to change that back, what seems to work for now is:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/mongoDB --bind_ip 172.17.0.3 --ipv6
```

then simply update the mongodb locator on the other container:

```
$conn = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://172.17.0.3:27017');
```

and vala! my blank containerised mongodb is assessable via IPv6 to a containerised web server
[image: IPv6 webserver displaying Mongodb]